# Array of ObjectIds ini php using mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

In the db I'm trying to create an array of ObjectIds that correlate to another collection. This is what I have in the db

```
"companies": [
        {
            "id": ObjectId("57fa9b25fc13ae1474002a94")
        },
        {
            "id": ObjectId("57fa9b25fc13ae1474002a97")
        }
    ]
```

When I look at what I get in postman it is

```
"companies": [
  {
    "id": {}
  },
  {
    "id": {}
  }
]
```

When I read in from the database the ObjectIds are there but when the function returns they don't get passed through. If I just use a single ObjectId it works but once I put in an array is when I run into issues. Should I be storing this differently in the db or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Please share some of your code which handles this part.